# How to improve rendering performance of SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a report with four charts, that each have one dataset behind it, the performance on the db side is very good, however I waste nearly 95% of the time on the rendering step of the report. Are there options within SSRS to improve the rendering efficiency?

Is there a way to get more detail information, where in the rendering process the time is being consumed?

- TimeDataRetrieval: 1624 ms
- TimeProcessing:    1633 ms
- TimeRendering:     51369 ms
- ByteCount:         35396
- RowCount:          128298

Comment: How long does it take to render the report?

Comment: yes, they are in ms, I put the information in the original question for better formating.

Comment: We are facing the same issue. I'd love to see more discussion on this. Here's a starting point: ["My report takes too long to render."](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522806.aspx#Render) (undated MSDN article).

Answer (score 0):

From the RowCount, it looks as though all individual records are being retrieved by the report, and that the report is summarising them on the graph. Have you tried doing the summarisation in the queries, and only rendering the summarised data in the report on the graphs?

Comment: Well I already do the summarisation in the database, the reports uses "Stepped Line Charts" do display prices and amounts on a time axis, so the amounts are already summed up in the db. The biggest chart has around 68'700 records to be drawn in the stepped line.

Comment: Are you saying you have 68,700 datapoints on one (stepped line) chart? How can that be displayed?

Comment: Yes, but this is something very common for financial charts. How it looks ? Well I would say very good. Test it in Excel.